# Chart.js V2 line chart missing point

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

Is there any way to get missing links connected in Chart.js 2.x.x like they linked in last versions of 1.x.

If i had datasets in version 1.x with data [1,2,3,null,5,6] and [1,2,3,4,5,6], chart drew both lines without missing line on null point. On version 2.x linechart won't draw any line on set 1 between points 3 and 5.

I have tried to read chart.js documentation but haven't found any options to this...

Comment: There is opened issue for that: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new dataset option `spanGaps` that allows to connect dots with gaps between them.

Github commit for reference:

- https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/commit/77357e57d6f5ae44ba10bf22b06219850df4df5f